# Efficiently get caller in byte buddy's MethodDelegation

Tags: java, reflection, bytecode, byte-buddy, javaagents

I am trying to build a call tree in my java agent with byte buddy library. To add elements to the tree I want to use method delegation. However, to make sure who is the parent of any leaf, I need to know who called the method.

I don't want to use:

```
sun.reflect.Reflection#getCallerClass(int)
```

Because it's deprecated and unavailable in Java 8+.
Also, I tried:

```
public class ThreadUtil {

public static StackTraceElement getCaller() {
    Instant now = Instant.now();
    StackTraceElement ste = Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[3];
    String callerClass = ste.getClassName();
    String callerMethod = ste.getMethodName();
    Instant now2= Instant.now();
    System.out.println(Duration.between(now, now2));
    return ste;
}
```

}

But, it's extremely slow(~1 ms - too much if I have thousands of calls).

Is there a way to get caller efficiently at this point (maybe some byte buddy's tricks)?

P.S. 
My agent:

```
private static void instrument(String agentOps, Instrumentation inst) {
    System.out.println("Agent");
    new AgentBuilder.Default().with(new Eager())
            .ignore(ElementMatchers.nameContains("com.dvelopp.agenttest"))
            .type((ElementMatchers.any()))
            .transform((builder, typeDescription, classLoader, module) -> builder.method(ElementMatchers.any())
                    .intercept(MethodDelegation.to(Interceptor.class))).installOn(inst);
}

public static class Interceptor {

    @RuntimeType
    public static Object intercept(@SuperCall Callable<?> zuper, @Origin Method method,
                                   @AllArguments Object[] args, @This(optional = true) Object me) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("CURRENT: " + method.getDeclaringClass().getName());
        System.out.println("CALLER: " + ThreadUtil.getCaller().getClassName());
        return zuper.call();
    }

}
```

*ENV: Java 8*

Comment: `sun.reflect.Reflection#getCallerClass(int)` is not just deprecated—it never was part of the official API in the first place. Starting with Java 9, the official way is [`StackWalker.getCallerClass()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/StackWalker.html#getCallerClass()).

Comment: @Holger, I came across StackWalker. It looks amazing. But, currently I want my agent to support Java 8 apps(I added that to the question). Thank you!

Comment: Just use `StackWalker` when you are in a Java 9 JRE and fall back to the deprecated method in the older JREs. There is no official way for the older environments and the deprecated method won’t disappear in these environments.

Comment: What's about Java 8? It was removed in JDK 8 and StackWalker isn't still there.

Comment: In my Java 8 installation, it’s still present.

Comment: When I try to use it in JDK 8 even like this:
   @CallerSensitive
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Reflection.getCallerClass();
    }
I get errors. e.g. 
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InternalError: CallerSensitive annotation expected at frame 1
Before that I had like Class not found exception

Comment: Nothing in that error message indicates that `Reflection.getCallerClass` did not exist. You can not find the caller class of the `main` method because the `main` method does not have a caller class. That would also fail when trying to use `StackWalker.getCallerClass()` in the `main` method .

Comment: @Holger, you are absolutely right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Byte code instrumentation only allows you to generate code that you could also write yourself. For your case, you would need to create a fairly intrusive instrumentation that I would not recommend:

1. Instrument your target method to accept a new parameter of type `Class`.
2. Instrument every caller to supply their type as an additional argument.

The better solution is surely what Holger suggested in the comments. Use `StackWalker` and if not available, fall back to `sun.reflect.Reflection` (which is present in all JVMs I know of).

Comment: Does it really work for you on JDK 8? Try    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Reflection.getCallerClass();
    }
It's compiled, but it throws error :Exception in thread "main" java.lang.InternalError: CallerSensitive annotation expected at frame 1
 at sun.reflect.Reflection.getCallerClass(Native Method)
 at hello.ServiceInstanceRestController.main

Comment: It does work for me. What JDK version and from what vendor are you using?

Comment: The problem was due to me invoking it from the main method as Holger said.